# Iterate through rows in pandas dataframe and match values in a dictionary of lists to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use a dictionary to fuzzy match a column in a pandas dataframe. My dictionary looks like this:

```
{
      "customer name 1": {
         "aliases": [
            "custname1",
            "customer name 1",
            "name 1",
         ]
      },
...
}
```

The goal is to use the list `aliases` to match strings in a column of my dataframe, then generate a new column which would have `customer name 1` if it found a match. My dataframe has 26 columns, but the only one I use is a column named `Business Name`. Unfortunately, I need to read all the columns in because I need to output all of them to a new csv file at the end.

I've generated a solution which works on a small set of data, but I've found that for a larger set of data it takes much longer than I had hoped for. Currently this is what I have running:

```
def create_aggregate_names(workbook: str, names: dict, sheet: str) -> None:
    if '.xlsx' in workbook:
        wb = pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet_name=sheet)
    else:
        chunks = pd.read_csv(workbook, sep='|', encoding='latin-1', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False,chunksize=1000000)
    path = Path(workbook).parents[0]
    # Parse through rows to create an aggregate business name
    for chunk in chunks:
        if "Aggregate Business Name" not in chunk.columns:
            chunk["Aggregate Business Name"] = ""
        for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
            aggregate_name = str(row["Business Name"])
            for name in names:
                if any(alias in str(row["Business Name"]).lower() for alias in names[name]["aliases"]):
                    aggregate_name = name
            chunk.at[index, 'Aggregate Business Name'] = str(aggregate_name)
        chunk.to_csv("{}/data.csv".format(path), sep='|', index=False, mode='a')
```

I'm able to run this perfectly well with a csv file that has less than 1 million lines. Once I get over 1 million lines, the script runs seemingly forever with no output. Is there a way to do this with large data sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you could simplify your dictionary by removing the level `aliases` :

```
dict_ = {
      "customer name 1": 
          [
            "custname1",
            "customer name 1",
            "name 1",
         ],
    "customer name 2": ['custom name 2']

      }
```

Then, we can use a double list comprehension for faster computation :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_name' : ['custname1', 'custome name 2', "name 1"]})

df['real_name'] = [ [y for y in dict_ if x in dict_[y]][0] 
                     if len([y for y in dict_ if x in dict_[y]])>0 else ''             
                     for x in df['customer_name'] ]
```

Output :

```
    customer_name        real_name
0       custname1  customer name 1
1  custom  name 2  customer name 2
2          name 1  customer name 1
```

---

Note : We compute the list `[y for y in dict_ if x in dict_[y]` twice in the list comprehension which is a shame. But this will be avoidable in python 3.8 using the [walrus operator](https://www.codementor.io/ruturajkiranvaidya/introduction-to-python-3-8-new-feature-the-walrus-operator-vcv2d3zxw)

Comment: Glad I could help ! If this answer solved your issued don't forget to accept it by clicking on the green tick next to the answer. This helps  to keep the focus on unanswered questions